# Boolean value not saving in display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ransack

I have a Class Company with a boolean attribute of female_founder.
The company either has a female_founder (true) or not (false).

I have created a search filter using the ransack gem to query whether a company is female-founded or not. When I query 'true' searches, the enum value saves and displays fine, but when I search for the 'false' value, the display resets to the prompt value I have given it.

Why is this? And how can I fix it? I want the display to show whichever value I have selected.

#### Schema

```
create_table "companies", force: :cascade do |t|
 ...
 t.boolean  "female_founder"
 ...
end
```

#### Company.rb

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
 enum female_founders: {
  'Yes' => 1,
  'No' => 0
 }
end
```

#### Search.html.erb

```
<%= f.label :female_founder_eq, 'Female Founder' %>
<%= f.select :female_founder_eq, Company.female_founders.to_a, {prompt: "Any"} %>
```

Search 'Yes' for female_founder returns correct display

[image: Search 'Yes' for female_founder]

Search 'No' for female_founder resets search display to prompt value. 
The search queries correctly, it is just the display that is incorrect. 
[image: Search 'No' for female_founder]

Comment: Hi @Brian, Could you show the value of `params[:q][: female_founder_eq]` ?

Comment: Just a general question, why do you use an enum if you can use a boolean attribute directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's where Rails determines whether to add the prompt, in rails/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tags/base.rb:

```
      def add_options(option_tags, options, value = nil)
        if options[:include_blank]
          option_tags = tag_builder.content_tag_string("option", options[:include_blank].kind_of?(String) ? options[:include_blank] : nil, value: "") + "\n" + option_tags
        end
        if value.blank? && options[:prompt]
          option_tags = tag_builder.content_tag_string("option", prompt_text(options[:prompt]), value: "") + "\n" + option_tags
        end
        option_tags
      end
```

When Rails is building its select tag, it's determining whether to include a prompt by using `blank?`, which can't distinguish whether it's `nil` or `false`; because `@company.female_founder` is `false`, and `false` is `blank?`, it will assume no value was given and add the prompt.  (This may or may not be intentional on their part.)

Now, the `value` here is the tag's selected value, which can be overriden if the `:selected` option is defined, so if `:selected` is manually set to your No value of `0`, then it should suppress the prompt as expected (because `0` is not `blank?`).  Here's a kludge that appears to work for me for a regular form:

```
# 1 if true - show 'Yes', 0 if false - show 'No', nil if nil - show 'Any'
<%= f.select :female_founder, Company.female_founders.to_a, { prompt: "Any", selected: { true => 1, false => 0 }[@company.female_founder] } %>
```

For ransack it'll need to look something like this:

```
<%= f.select :female_founder_eq, Company.female_founders.to_a, {prompt: "Any", selected: { true => 1, false => 0 }[@q.base[:female_founder_eq].try(:value)] } %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried the solution you've suggested above but still no look. The display in the drop-down still reverts back to 'Any' after the search is done.

Comment: @BrianOHalloran I've looked into it a bit more and it looks like for ransack specifically the thing you'd use for `:selected` is `@q.base[:female_founder_eq].try(:value)` (where `@q` is whatever your query is) and I've updated my answer - can you try again?

Comment: you are amazing! Works perfectly. Thanks so much for your help!